# Task Scheduler in Server 2016 Datacenter Edition Dont automatic Run

Tags: windows, server, taskscheduler

We are migrating some applications and we use the windos Task Scheduler as a tool.

Migrate from Server 2012 Datacenter for Server 2016 Datacenter.

I create the tasks in several ways, importing from task scheduler in 2012 server, manually or using Poweshell but the scenario is the same. Despite having the recurrence for every 15 minutes and updating the "Next Runtime" field, the tasks do not start.

I did not find Error Log in the Service or Event Viewer of Windos.

Info About the Task:

Top Privileges Checked
Running a System Account
When you press Start it works perfectly.
Before Migration, Windows Server 2012 worked correctly.

[Print to Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tvnx.jpg)

Some help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I believe your question is more suitable to [ServerFault](serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future

I ran into this issue also. Posted my work-around there.